# Syndication Feeds in Joomla 1.6 not displaying link to XML

Tags: joomla, rss, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

I have enabled Syndication Feeds then created RSS Feed module to display it in the footer of a web site but I have hit into issue that RSS Feed link is empty.

Site is located here http://holyapostlesnyc.org

Any idea what can be wrong? We are running Joomla 1.6.0

Thanks

PS.
When I have added menu as category list I am able to user raw output to RSS Feed http://holyapostlesnyc.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=8&format=feed&type=rss

Maybe it will help to find out why is not working by default?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your feed link is dead, something is not working properly. I assume you to use some component for your feed generator
Take a look here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/rss-syndicate
Also, upgrade your joomla website, the 1.6 version is not supported anymore. 2.5 is the up and running version

Comment: I'm using core component Syndication Feeds from 1.6. I will try any from attached link to see if it will work. Thanks